# How to return to main menu in switch case after executing a method?

Tags: java

How do I get get the menu to display again after the selected method executes?

I have the menu option print to the console. Then it takes user input (1 - 6), calls according method, and then *should* return to the menu for the user to select from the menu again.

After the selected method executes, the program just ends.

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    String mainMenu = ("Select a choice from the menu: \n" 
            + "1. Add new DVD entry\n" 
            + "2. Look Up DVD Entry\n"
            + "3. Display DVDs By Category\n" 
            + "4. Remove DVD Entry\n"
            + "5. Save Data\n" 
            + "6. Exit");

    System.out.println(mainMenu);

    menuChoice = kbd.nextInt();

    while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 6) {
        System.out.print("\nError! Incorrect choice.\n");
        System.out.println(mainMenu);
        menuChoice = kbd.nextInt();
    }

    switch (menuChoice) {
    case 1: {
        // method code
        }
        else {
            // method code
            return;
        }
    }

    case 2: {
        // method code
        return;
    }

    case 3: {
        // method code
        return;
    }

    case 4: {
        // method code
        return;
    }   

    case 5: {
        // method code
        return;
    }

    case 6: {
        // method code
        System.exit(0);
        return;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: wrap the `switch (menuChoice){...}` inside `while`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a do while

```
do
{
    System.out.println(mainMenu);

    menuChoice = kbd.nextInt();

   ... switch/case ...
   ... remove the return statements from your cases.

} while (menuChoice != 6);
```

You also have to remove the `return` from your `case`s. Otherwise it will return out of main. Replace them with `break`;

This is how switch cases need to be

```
switch (menuChoice) 
{
    case 1: 
        Do what you want. 
        break;
    case 2:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
}
```

You don't usually need `{` or `if` inside the switch case.

Comment: I've tried this, but it still doesn't go back to the main menu.

Comment: @trama - have you removed the returns from your case statements. Updated the answer to add this.

Comment: @user935553 I did, but it went on to the next case/ method. But I then replaced the 'returns' with 'break' and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code inside

```
  while(menuChoice != 6) 
    { 
      ... 
    }
```