# How to return to a main menu from switch if it's declared as a String?

Tags: java

I have a Main Menu in my program inside a while loop. The list has 1 for option one, 2 for option two and q||Q to quit. What do I have to put into the while loop to return if my switch statement is a String.
This is a link I found but they're using int.
[How to return to main menu in switch case after executing a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857846/how-to-return-to-main-menu-in-switch-case-after-executing-a-method)

```
do {
final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
String mainMenu = ("Main Menu\n\n" + "1 : Option 1\n" + "2 : Option2\n"
            + "Q : Quit\n");

        System.out.println(mainMenu);
String choice = console.next();
switch (choice)    
case "1":
...
case "2":
...
case "q":
case "Q":
...
} while (choice !=2);
```

Comment: What does "my switch statement is a String" mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter I think he means the control variable is a `String`.

Comment: Why do you have this  'while (choice !=2);'   when you are wanting to quit the loop when it's Q or q? and... why  2   instead of "2". Seems the types are getting confused.

Comment: oh and break breaks out of a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your switch in a loop but make sure to have a choice that exits with System.exit(error code). Everytime the user gives his input, your function executes then the program blocks again for user input. This keeps happening until they choose the terminal option.